# How to use mlflow.log_params to append params when used alongside mlflow.autolog()

Tags: mlflow

I am using mlflow.autolog() to log params and metrics for a tensorflow based training and it works well. It captures 26 different parameters automatically.
However if I use mlflow.log_params() to log custom params those 26 are not being logged anymore. I am wondering if there is a way to append params alongside regular params?

Comment: Have you found any solution yet?